# Fail to find a function in yaml.h library (C)

Tags: c, yaml, undefined-reference

I try to read a yml file in C (Code::Blocks IDE) but I receive an undefined reference error for yaml_parser_initialize:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <yaml.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fh = fopen("configuration.yaml", "r");
    yaml_parser_t parser;

    /* Initialize parser */
    if(!yaml_parser_initialize(&parser))
        fputs("Failed to initialize parser!\n", stderr);
    
    fclose(fh);    
    return 0;}
```

The function exists in yaml.h. I linked the yaml library as follows:

1. Project->Build Options->Linker Settings: added src\.libs\libyaml.a
2. Project->Build Options->Search Directories->Compiler: added the include library: yaml-0.2.5\include.
3. Project->Build Options->Search Directories->Linker: added the include library: yaml-0.2.5\include.

OS: Win10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update you tags. add an OS you use. it seems that you supply a wrong path to linker. `src.libs\libyaml.a` is defly wrong on `Linux`

Comment: I'm using win 10. Sorry I had a small typo, it should have been src.\libs\libyaml.a.

Comment: once again, **update tags of the question**. supply your `OS`. `libyaml.a` is a wrong library for `Windows OS`. Windows libraries usually have a different file ending: not an **`.a`**, but **`.lib`** or **`.dll`**

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the tags I've added, what should  I update it to? OS was added. There are no .lib or .dll files in the yaml folder (only have .a and .so files) - maybe because I've installed it with vmware work station?

Comment: you still have no required tags in your question. your tags are: `c` `yaml` `undefined-reference`. you talk about `windows` OS, but you use `linux` libraries in the build envinronment. if the build envinronment is `linux`, then you should say so. if you run `linux` as a virtual machine and with that you building your application, then the libs should be linux `.a` or `.so`. **but**, the paths in Linux follow different convention than with Windows. in particular, directory separators in Linux are **/ (forward slash)**, not a **back slash**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I will try to answer that and update my answer per request.

If you building on `Linux` OS, no matter if your host OS is `Windows`(you may run Linux as a virtual machine), you usually link with **.a** or **.so** library files.

If you build envinronment is `Windows`, no matter the host OS, then you usually link with **.lib** or **.dll** libraries.

That being said, the above mentioned OS'es have a different convention about how to supply a path to file.
On `Linux` the path go like this: `/path/to/libs/libyaml.a`.
On `Windows` the path go like this `C:\Program Files\libs\yaml.lib`.

Any app that runs on the OS follow the OS path convention. In your case `Code::Blocks` request you to supply a path in the convention the guest OS is.

**The below text, is two methods of building your code with `yaml` library ob `Ubuntu`.**

**Update**

I do not use `Code::Blocks` as of now. I've installed the `IDE` to check what your options are.
You talk about `Ubuntu`, `C` and `yaml`. That will be:

**1)** `New Project`->`Console Application`->`C`.

**2)** `<Whichever project names you wish>`

**3)** `<Whatever compiler configuration you like>`

That was to create a bunch of files that `CB` calls project. Now I dont know what sort of `yaml` library you use. But you talk about `Ubuntu` and `C` so...

**1)** `apt search libyaml`->`<guess what yaml are>`->`apt install libyaml-dev`

**2)** `pkg-config --list-all | grep yaml` gets me the output of `yaml-0.1`. That is the name I want to supply as argument to `pkg-config`.

BTW you seem to get a different version of `yaml` library. But still, all we need is to know proper strings to supply as compiler and linker arguments.

**3)** `pkg-config --libs` gets me `-lyaml`

**4)** `pkg-config --cflags` gets me empty line. So the include path is well-known for the build envinronment

This way, we know the linker arguments(`-lyaml`) and the compiler arguments(`<empty string>`). Now I try to insert them somewhere where `CB` could find them.

**1)** Menu options: `Project`->`Build options...`
**2)** `Compiler settings`-> no change
**3)** `Linker settings`->`link libraries`->**`yaml`**

**The libraries in `CB` should go **without** `-l` prefix, so it should be as above. Hit build and all went OK.**

**Update for git version**

It seems that your yaml version is newer than my distro version. If you need recent version, lets go and install that from git.

**1)** `apt remove libyaml-dev`. So that there will be no clashes with the library versions.

I did choose the [Canonical repository for libyaml](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml) as my distro is `Ubuntu`. You need to `mkdir` for the sources and `cd` to that directory.

**2)** `git clone https://github.com/yaml/libyaml`

**3)** `cd libyaml`

**4)** Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml) to build and install.

**5)** `pkg-config --list-all | grep yaml` gets me `yaml-0.1`
**6)** `pkg-config --cflags yaml-0.1` produces `-I/usr/local/include`
**7)** `pkg-config --libs yaml-0.1` gets this `-L/usr/local/lib -lyaml`

Ok we got the compiler & linker flags for the library. The `link library` option stays the same. You need to add `-L/usr/local/lib` to `Other linker options`. I did not find where I could add the compiler flags, so I'had added new flag. In `CB` that will be `Compiler flags`->`<right mouse click>`->`New flag`. Name the flag somehow and insert the `-I/usr/local/include` string to the `Compiler flags` input row. Hit `OK` button. Hit the checkbox in front of your newly created flag. Build & Run.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same error in Ubuntu. The code is the same, instead in the include line which is now reads the full path to yaml.h: 
#include </mnt/hgfs/yaml-0.2.5/include/yaml.h>

Comment: @yonatan see my updates as of how you can build with `libyaml` on `Ubuntu`.